# Usage of generics as parameter in c#

Tags: c#, generics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DesignPatterns
{
    public class Composite
    {
        public Composite()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am Composite class constructor");
        }

        public void add()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Added to Composite class");
        }
    }

    public class Component
    {
        public Component()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am Component class constructor");
        }

        public void add()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Added to Component class");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call add functions in above code. I do not want to use interfaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DesignPatterns
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Examp().Add(new Component());
            new Examp().Add(new Composite());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Examp
    {
        public void Add<T>(T classinstance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Added " + classinstance + " to the Examp class");
            ((Composite)classinstance).add();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a compiler error. If this is not possible in this way, how to use **classinstance** here?
(I tried to use generics similar to interface). If it is not possible, then what is the use of generics as parameter?

Comment: Why do you not want to use interfaces? The alternative (use a shared, possibly abstract base class) is actually *more* intrusive.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I am just trying to learn generics. So trying to know what is the use of generics as parameters for methods. (How can I make use of classinstance here?)

Comment: Well, I guess an appropriate answer would be *generic method parameters are not necessary here (and not really meant to be used that way)*. Generic method parameters really shine when the method takes or returns generic *types* (see [Enumerable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891.aspx) for an example).

Answer (score 2):

Make Composite and Component implement an interface

```
public interface IMyI
{
    void add();
}
```

Your two classes implement IMyI and change your Examp.Add to

```
public void Add<T>(T classinstance) where T : IMyI
{
    Console.WriteLine("Added " + classinstance + " to the Examp class");
    classinstance.add();
}
```

Comment: Note that in the simple example here, `Add(IMyI)` would give you  the same functionality, but be simpler.

Comment: @TimS. True, thanks for that. I was trying to show the usage of where but could've included your suggestion.

Comment: @artm I’m not sure why you reverted my edit, but you *cannot* call `add` on the generic type. `T` is a type, so `add` would need to be a static method of that type but generic types cannot have static methods.

Comment: @poke Sorry, late here, I thought I was accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

I would also strongly advice you using interfaces and similar solution provided in @artm. But if you really do not want to use interface, you can use `dynamic` parameter and change your `Add` method in `Examp` class:

```
public void Add(dynamic classinstance)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Added " + classinstance + " to the Examp class");
    classinstance.add();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use interfaces, and your `Add` method actually just does something like that, you could also just provide an overload for both types:

```
public void Add (Composite classinstance)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Added " + classinstance + " to the Examp class");
    classinstance.add();
}

public void Add (Component classinstance)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Added " + classinstance + " to the Examp class");
    classinstance.add();
}
```

But if you plan to add these objects to something, for example a collection, you should definitely use a common base type, e.g. an interface as the others suggested, so that you retain their type instead of having to add them as information-less `object`s.

Then you could just use the interface to access things:

```
private List<IAddable> list = new List<IAddable>();

public void Add (IAddable obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Added {0} to the Examp class", obj);
    list.Add(obj); // actually add the object to some collection
    obj.add();
}
```